# htaccess Redirect directory name to parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory, param

I would like to redirect all paths like this:

```
myurl.com/worldwide/en
myurl.com/worldwide/pt
myurl.com/worldwide/de
```

to:

```
myurl.com/worldwide/index.php?lang=en
myurl.com/worldwide/index.php?lang=pt
myurl.com/worldwide/index.php?lang=de
```

Just to be clear a dynamic redirection of the pathname after `/worldwide`

Actually ideally I would like to keep the original url (e.g. `myurl.com/worldwide/de`) but load the same php file with the language directory as a param but not sure if this is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /worldwide/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please let me know if this helps you

Comment: Almost perfect thanks very much! Just needed to remove the `/` from `^(.*)$ index.php?/lang=$1 [L,QSA]`. `$1` Resolves to e.g. `worldwide/en` instead of `en` but not a problem I can just strip it out in php. Glad it doesn't change the url either thanks

Comment: Thanks... Please appreciate the same by accepting it as an answer

Comment: I will (have to wait a minimum amount of minutes)

Comment: How come when I put a `/` all the way at the end, it doesn't load any external resources (css, images)?

Comment: @Dan the Man: Sorry, I am not able to understand you. Can you please share the piece of code that you want to use

Comment: If I change RewriteBase to / then this works for something like example.com/test - that is, it will load index.php?lang=test . But if I actually have a folder in my www root named 'test', it returns the contents of that folder. Is it possible to force it to return index.php?lang=test instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This works. If you add some explanation to why, you have my up-vote.