# How to simplify PHP site URL using htaccess rewrite rule?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have this site made from the developer in PHP and now all the pages have this URL structure,

websitename.com/software.php?name=product_name

The only thing which changes every time on various pages on site is only the "product name" such as:

websitename.com/software.php?name=product_name1

websitename.com/software.php?name=product_name2

websitename.com/software.php?name=product_name3

etc

I only want to have URL like this:

websitename.com/product_name1

websitename.com/product_name2

websitename.com/product_name3 
and so on..

can you please tell me what code should I be adding on my htaccess in order to get such URL structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess Redirect directory name to parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662957/htaccess-redirect-directory-name-to-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

For websitename.com/any to websitename.com/software.php?name=any use this rules in top of yours .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /software.php?name=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But more usefull URL structure (software only for products) would be websitename.com/software/any-product-name to websitename.com/software.php?name=any-product-name

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^software\/(.*)$ /software.php?name=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

For SEO friendly URLs use "-" instead of "_" in product names.

Comment: its working fine mate but both of the links are available, can you tell me code through which I can 301 redirect the old URL structure to new URL structure, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /software.php?name=$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

---

UPDATE: In the comment below you ask in addition to redirect a request to the original, not rewritten URL. Here is an extended version doing that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)name=([^&]+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?software\.php$ /%1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /software.php?name=$1 [END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

Comment: not working mate, it's giving 500 server error, tried with [L] as well at the end but still no url structure changes

Comment: The below code is working but can you tell me code through which the old url structure can be 301 redirected to the new url structure in the meantime, thanks                <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /software.php?name=$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: The Updated code is still not working, i am still having the same old url, no redirections are there.

Comment: That means that the rules to not get applied at all. Please specify the _exact_ URL you try and also where you implemented those rules. How did you make sure that such dynamic rules get evaluated _at all_ ?

Comment: the project is under going so maybe i can't keep that code on htaccess always but for you to look at it i will setup it somewhere else, if possible can we chat about it on facebook? i will really appreciate it

Comment: Sure, we can have a direct discussion, but not on Facebook, I don't use that one. SO here offers chatrooms which are perfectly adequate for that. I can only attend to this in the evening, though, since I am busy at work currently. You create a chat room and post the link in a comment here. I will try to enter that room this evening, say around 8ish central european time. Is that fine with you?

Comment: Hm, you did not create a room? Why not? OK, I did it myself, will look into it from time to time. Just write, I will pick you up. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197962/andrew-arkascha

Comment: i am really sorry for such delay response I check your chat room link but its saying you must have 20 reputation on stackoverflow to talk there

Comment: please if not facebook then create your preferable chat room, i,ll be waiting

Comment: There is no way around the 20 points minimum limit to be able to talk in chat rooms. That limit does make sense, I did not realize you do not yet have those point. I upvoted your question, but that still only leaves you with 11 points. Unconvenient in this situation, any way you want to try to gain those few points? . I do not use facebook for various social and political reasons, sorry for that.

Comment: i understand, m trying to get it to 20reputations as well. Thing is i totally lost access to my old account in here and that is why i had to make a new one recently,

Comment: Hey, the 301 redirection issue has been resolved, thankyou so much anyways, cheers