# htaccess redirect with parameter doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to create a redirection from short to real URL but can't find the right way to achieve this:

short URL  : `mysite.com/aZerTy123`

real URL  : `mysite.com/mypage.html?aZerTy123`

I've tried different solutions found here on STOV but the prob remains the same: `mypage.html` is opened but no way to get the code.

On mypage.html:

```
let code = location.search.substring(1,location.search.length);
console.log('code='+code)
```

Opening the real full URL gives `code=aZerTy123` as expected but opening it with htaccess gives `code=` in console ... how to catch it?

My htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ mypage.html?$1 [L]
```

Comment: Javascript runs on client side only and your rewrite is happening in web server. To be able to fetch query string you need to use backend script like php, perl, python etc

Comment: thanks for answer. Sorry  don't exactly understand what you mean: it should work with "mypage.php/code" ? see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662957/htaccess-redirect-directory-name-to-parameter

Comment: works with `let code=location.href.split("/").slice(-1);`
console.log('code='+code) // code=aZerTy123

Comment: That's not query string btw